# Unable to import 'tal_módulo'

Tags: python, vscode, python-import

Últimamente codifico empleando el editor Visual Studio Code. En principio, me va todo bien.

Si acaso, me pasa algo cuando hago `import` de algún módulo o archivo creado por mí, o cualquier otro archivo personalizado que haya descargado de terceros.

La ejecución del programa no me da fallo alguno. Solo es molesto que el Pylint dé avisos sin sentido diciendo o mostrando, por lo general, este mensaje con el nombre del módulo al que se refiere, por ejemplo, 'tal_modulo':

```
[pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'tal_modulo'
```

He buscado por Internet advertencias parecidas y dicen como si hubiese que entrar en la configuración del Visual Studio Code para especificar el tanto el PATH del Python empleado como el del Pylint dónde está instalado.

En cierto post, se mencionaba que para saber dónde está Python y Pylint, se ejecuta esto en la terminal de Ubuntu:

```
which python
```

lo que me da

```
/usr/bin/python
```

y

```
which pylint
```

lo que me da

```
/home/user/.local/bin/pylint
```

Por otro lado, se recomienda seleccionar el entorno o versión de Python a aplicar al proyecto activo. Algo que se puede hacer desde la propia barra de estado del programa. Ahí, tengo seleccionada la versión 2.7.12 de Python (algo que, si dejo el cursor encima de esa señalización, marca esta url >> `/usr/bin/python`, lo mismo que me da el comando `which python` como antes he señalado).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que parece claro es que todas estas advertencias es algo referente a no sé qué configuración de Visual Code relacionada con Python y Pylint.

En otros resultados de búsqueda de Google, dicen como que si hay que especificar los parámetros `"python.pythonPath"` y `"python.linting.pylintPath"` del archivo de preferencias de Visual Studio Code.
En mi configuración, por defecto, estos dos parámetros tienen estos valores:

```
"python.pythonPath": "python"
"python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint"
```

He probado a poner estos valores (es decir, los valores que me dan los comandos de `which python` y `which pylint`) en la parte de la configuración del usuario:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/user/.local/bin/pylint"
```

He guardado los cambios y reiniciado el editor pero las advertencias/errores indicados de Pylint siguen  señalando lo mismo.
Ya digo que, en cuanto a la ejecución del lo programado no tiene efecto alguno y va todo bien. Pero, bueno solo era por si se puede hacer algo para corregir que no interprete cosas como malas cuando están bien.

Si alguien sabe como corregir esto ... ¿algo que no configuro bien?

Saludos.

---

**Editado**

Esta es la imagen de mi carpeta de trabajo en Visual Studio Code:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo que funciona como `main` es el último que está en rojo y es el que está abierto en el panel de la derecha y que muestra todos los supuestos errores o advertencias sobre los import.

En este caso, los archivos que se están importando están en la carpeta [libs] o en [db] del mismo proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente no estoy seguro de que es lo que pasa pero me di cuenta que cuando se está utilizando Visual Studio Code abriendo una carpeta que contenga al proyecto pasa ese tipo de errores, lo mejor es trabajar el proyecto desde la misma carpeta en el editor. 
No se si sea tu caso. Te dejo un ejemplo:

[image: Abriendo directamente el módulo donde trabajo]
[image: Abriendo la carpeta padre del módulo]

Ojalá te sirva. Al menos eso me ha quitado la molestia de los mensajes a mi.

Comment: ¡Vaya sorpresa!, no esperaba ya contestación sobre esto. He editado mi pregunta para añadir una imagen de mi espacio de trabajo. Por si acaso probé a cargar o a agregar, solamente, una carpeta al área de trabajo, como exponías en tu respuesta pero, aún y todo, me siguen saliendo esas "rayitas" rojas bajo los `import` o los `from` ... ¿por qué? No lo sé ... Quizás tengas, igual, otra idea que aportar ... ¿? Sino, gracias aún y todo por tu atención.